# Why can't I range-for over an initializer list of arbitrary stuff?

Tags: c++, c++14, initializer-list

In modern C++, the following compiles and runs as expected:

```
for(const auto& x : {"hello", "nice", "world"}) {
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

But if the initializer list has elements of different types, I can no longer get the code to compile:

```
for(const auto& x : {"hello", 123, '4'}) {
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

Why won't it compile and run? Can't this initializer list be understood as a 3-`tuple`? Or an initializer list of `experimental::any`s? Or something?

**Notes:**

- I used g++ 5.2.1 and `--std=c++14`; `--std=c++17` doesn't change anything.
- Suppose I've included all C++ standard library headers, as well as `<experimental/any>`.
- The compiler error is, of course, `unable to deduce ‘std::initializer_list<auto>&&’ from ‘{"hello", 123, '4'}’`.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that `s` is sometimes a string, sometimes an int, and sometimes a char? Variables can only have one type.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: Of course. Replaced `s` with `x` so as not to imply I'm expecting strings.

Answer (score 9):

> Can't this initializer list be understood as a 3-tuple? Or an initializer list of experimental::anys? Or something?

No.

That braced-init-list does not have a type, and it cannot be deduced as a type. It can be used to *initialize* something ... but for that to happen the compiler has to know what the "something" is.

In a range-based `for` statement the compiler generates the equivalent of this definition:

```
auto && __range = {"hello", 123, '4'} ;
```

but that is not valid C++, because the type of the braced-init-list is not known.

> Or an initializer list of `experimental::any`s?

**It can't be `std::experimental::any` because that isn't in the standard. You can't have the compiler magically interpret something as a library type defined in some other specification.** You'd need a built-in `any` type known to the compiler for that to work, and that would **never** get accepted by the committee (there are costs to using `any`, due to dynamic allocation and the indirections caused by type erasure, not to mention the fact you couldn't do something useful in the `for` loop without knowing the types).

If you want a sequence of `any` then say so:

```
for (auto i : std::initializer_list<std::experimental::any>{ a, b, c})
```

but what do you put in the loop body? You have to know the types of each element to do anything useful, and if you already know how many elements there are and all their types, why use a loop anyway? A loop is for doing the same thing repeatedly, not doing several different things to several different types.

I would suggest a better way to do that would be:

```
auto op = [](auto i) { /* do something with i */ }
op(a);
op(b);
op(c);
```

It would certainly be nice to have built-in language support for creating tuples (not `std::tuple`, but anonymous structs generated on the fly, similar to how lambdas create anonymous functions), but it definitely wouldn't involve indirection through `any`.

You can simulate something a bit like that using lambdas:

```
auto anon_struct = [a, b, c](auto func) { func(a); func(b); func(c); }
```

This creates a lambda that captures `a`, `b` and `c`, and allows you to call it with a function that will be applied to each of the variables:

```
auto op = [](auto i) { /* do something with i */ }
anon_struct(op);  // apply op to each "member" of the anon struct
```

Or maybe more usefully:

```
auto anon_struct = [a, b, c](auto visitor) { visitor(a, b, c); }
auto visitor1 = [](auto i, auto j, auto k) { /* do something with i */ }
auto visitor2 = [](auto i, auto j, auto k) { /* do something with j */ }
anon_struct(visitor1);
anon_struct(visitor2);
```

Comment: In both examples I haven't defined any "something" to be initialized. Now, ok, you could tell me "the initializer list doesn't really exist, it's only used to initialize an anonymous variable". Well, I would shrug, then. It seems to exist more than the anonymous does, at least as far as I the coder looking at my code am concerned...

Comment: Following your edit: You're not answering my question, which is - why should it not be known? If nothing else, can't it be a range of `experimental::any`s ?

Comment: I shrug back at you. That's how C++ works. It can't be `std::experimental::any` because that isn't in the standard. You can't have the compiler magically interpret something as a library type defined in some other specification. If you want that then say so: `for (auto i : std::initializer_list<std::experimental::any>{ a, b, c}) ...`

Comment: You can also make it a `std::tuple`, using `std::make_tuple(a, b, c)`, but you can't iterate over a `std::tuple`.

Comment: Re second-to-last comment: Now _that_ is an answer!

Comment: If you highlight/embolden the paragraph about why it'll never be `std::any`, I'll accept your answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

In the draft standard *18.9/p1 Initializer lists [support.initlist]* the initializer list class is defined as:

> ```
> template<class E> class initializer_list {
> ...
> }
> ```

Consequently, when you provide actually an aggregate initialization list with different types the question is, which one of the types must the compiler choose to deduce `E`?